# Handling errno in asm x86_64

Tags: assembly, x86-64, errno

so I'm working on a lib in asm x86_64 (intel syntax) that I would use in C files. I'm working on `write()`.
So basically I'm just doing a syscall with `rax` set to 0. Nothing difficult here. 
The only problem is in the error handling. I'm using the `__error_location` function to get the address of errno so I can set the corresponding value in case of an error. It works fine except for the size errors. 
For example, if I put an invalid file descriptor, the error would be "Bad address", good. But if I put a negative size in 3rd parameter (`rdx`), then I get "Success" with wrong characters written. I would like to understand why, and how to correct it if anyone knows. Thanks a lot

ft_write.s

```
section .text
    global ft_write
    extern __errno_location

ft_write: 
    mov rax, 1
    syscall

    cmp rax, 0
    jl error
    ret 

error:
    neg rax 
    push rax 
    pop rbx 
    call __errno_location
    mov [rax], rbx 
    mov rax, -1
    ret
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>

int ft_write(int fd, void *buffer, int buffer_size);

extern int errno ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ft_write(1, "1", 1); 
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    write(1, "1", 1); 
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));

    ft_write(-1, "1", 1); 
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    write(-1, "1", 1); 
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));

    ft_write(1, "1", -1);
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    write(1, "1", -1);
    printf("\n%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return (0);
}
```

The output :
[image: the output]

I also tried to hard code a condition to set errno to 14 if `rdx < 0` but I couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: For starters, why the `push rdx`/`pop rax`? That overwrites the result from the syscall which may be different. I believe `errno` is 32 bit, so don't write 64 bits to it.

Comment: Hmm actually yeah that was stupid. Now that I think about it. I'll edit it thanks. I tried with 32 bits and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Your prototype is wrong, the `buffer_size` is not an `int`. Also note that not all negative values are errors.

Comment: Oh wow, it was the int. I put a `size_t` and it worked. But why is that ? Size_t is an unsigned integer data type so if I put in -1 it would translate to UINT_MAX - 1 right ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes but the syscall treats it as 64 bit so instead of -1 it will see something like 4 billion. PS: you might be interested in `strace`.

Comment: Yeah but 4 billion is valid as a buffer_size so how does it know it's an error ? Thanks I'll look into it

Comment: It is valid but you don't have that much memory mapped so it faults.

Comment: Got it, thank you !